# I can't deploy to artifactory Google Cloud

Tags: kotlin, artifactory, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I created a free artifactory server on Google Cloud and I'm trying to deploy it, but I have the following error:

> Execution failed for task ':artifactoryDeploy'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: Could not publish build-info: This plugin is compatible with version 2.2.3 of Artifactory and above. Please upgrade
> > your Artifactory server!

My Gradle config

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject
import org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.dsl.PublisherConfig

plugins {
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"
  id("com.jfrog.artifactory") version "4.17.2"
  `maven-publish`
}

group = "com.rjdesenvolvimento"
version = "0.0.1"

repositories {
  jcenter()
  maven { url = uri("https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor") }
}

dependencies {
  implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
  api("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0")
  api("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5:1.4.10")
  api("io.mockk:mockk:1.10.2")
}

tasks {
  compileKotlin { kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11" }
  compileTestKotlin { kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11" }
}

publishing {
  publications {
    create<MavenPublication>("kotlin") {
      from(components["kotlin"])
    }
  }
}

artifactory {
  setContextUrl("https://some-addressjfrog.io/artifactory/artifact/")
  publish(delegateClosureOf<PublisherConfig> {
    repository(delegateClosureOf<GroovyObject> {
      setProperty("repoKey", "aries-develop")
      setProperty("username", "some-user")
      setProperty("password", "some=password")
      setProperty("maven", true)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: I think that is an artifactory question and not related to Google Cloud

Comment: Which Artifactory version do you use?

Comment: 4.17.2 - plugin. and 7.7 my server

Comment: My bet it - The context URL looks wrong. Please try this context URL:
`https://some-addressjfrog.io/artifactory`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with using a wrong Artifactory URL (as indicated by @yahavi in the comments).
Please make sure that you are using the root Artifactory context, for example:

```
https://some-address.jfrog.io/artifactory/
```

The error message from the plugin is misleading and is updated in version 3.9.0 of the Jenkins Artifactory plugin.For more details see this Github [issue](https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/pull/395).

Comment: The fix is included in the latest Jenkins Artifactory plugin, 3.9.0.